Django Social Authentication Issue: Unable to Login Using Facebook or LinkedIn
I'm facing an issue with integrating social authentication (Google, Facebook, LinkedIn) into my Django web application using social-auth-app-django. While Google login works fine, I'm unable to get Facebook or LinkedIn login to function correctly.
Login | Facebook Error | Linkedin Error | Linkedin Error2
I followed the setup instructions for social-auth-app-django and configured the keys and secrets for Google, Facebook, and LinkedIn in my settings.py. Google authentication works as expected, redirecting users to the correct page after login. However, when attempting to log in using Facebook or LinkedIn, the authentication process fails silently without any clear error message or redirection.Steps Taken:
Verified client IDs and secrets for Facebook and LinkedIn are correctly set in settings.py.
Ensured correct scopes and field selectors are configured for LinkedIn.
Checked that all necessary middleware and context processors are included in settings.py.
from pathlib import Path
import os
import logging

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-@*#c*5am%k5_-@#axxxxxxxxxxxah=(h9pbnf!z-x01h@n#66'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'demo',
    'social_django',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'signin.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'signin.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

LOGIN_URL = "/"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/home"
LOGOUT_URL = "/logout"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = "52xxx507974-llhuvt20815sexxxxxbnslt7pdro0hs.apps.googleusercontent.com"
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = "GOCSPXxxxxxoYPEAtpgxxxxGLsoW0"

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '486xxxx04xxx39'  
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'f9c4xxxx05f407dcdd81e2xxxxx7e'

SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_KEY = "77ih4kxxxxa56"
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SECRET = "sExxxxmexlCxxNe"

SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [ 'email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_FIELD_SELECTORS = [
    'id', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'email-address', 'public-profile-url', 'picture-url'
]
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_EXTRA_DATA = [
    ('id', 'id'),
    ('firstName', 'first_name'),
    ('lastName', 'last_name'),
    ('emailAddress', 'email_address'),
    ('pictureUrl', 'picture_url'),
    ('publicProfileUrl', 'profile_url'),
]

SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGGER = 'social_auth'
SOCIAL_AUTH_RAISE_EXCEPTIONS = False

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    handlers=[logging.StreamHandler()]
)


